# spring-data repository custom query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using a spring boot application with a postgres database, and i do get an exception at the startup time.

The exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/projection/ProjectionFactory;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

I tried to create a repository with a custom query, which looks like:

```
public interface LastRunRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LastRun, Long> {
    LastRun findFirst1OrderByStartDateDesc();
}
```

My LastRun Entity looks like:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(name = "last_run")
public class LastRun {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="start_date", nullable = false)
    private Date startDate;

    public LastRun() {
    }

    public LastRun(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LastRun{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", startDate=" + startDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

If i am using just the standard queries, like find or save, it works like a charm. But as soon as i define a custom query it throws me this exception.

In mvn dependency:tree i can see that i get the spring-data-jpa 1.9.4 version from the sprint-boot-starter-data-jpa.

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.32:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.32:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.1.RELEASE:compile
```

I am using the latest versions of spring-data-jpa and spring-data-commons.

So, spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.1.RELEASE and spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE), are not compatible?

Comment: Looks like you are using incompatible versions of jars. Spring Data Commons 1.12 is the most recent one, whereas spring data JPA 1.9 is the previous one which depends on commons 1.11.

Comment: Thanks, i updated the original question, please have a look

Comment: You aren't using the latests versions... 1.9 isn't the latest, 1.10 is... Can you post your pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I confirm this was due to incompatible spring data and spring boot dependencies.

Example of pom.xml:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

In above pom, Eclipse raise a warning, overriding manage version `1.3.4.RELEASE` and if you start your app you will get the described exception.

You should remove the version and use the same dependecies as the one given in `spring-boot-starter-parent`:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use like this
 LastRun findByStartDateDesc(Pageable pageable);

in Pageable pageable parameter you can pass argument as new PageRequest(0,size)
where size represents the how many records you want.

Comment: i guess for method name is incorrect it wouldn't work.may be some compatibility issue are there but first check                                       'LastRun findFirst1OrderByStartDateDesc();' this also incorrect.At run time  you came to know.try it by fixing compatibility issue you still get exception at run time @ M. Deinum